# How to fix "isproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, installshield

I'm trying InstallShield project to create an installations using Visual studio TFS 2012. But, setup file is not being generated. When I looked into the error log, it says `"isproj is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built"`
Let me know what is the fix for this issue.

Comment: What version (express, pro, premiere, limited ) of InstallShield are you using and is your  TFS  on-prem or cloud base (Visual Studio Online)?  If VSO,  is your build controller on prem or cloud provisioned?

Comment: No matter which version of InstallShield you own or install on this machine, that error message shows it does not contain the required MSBuild targets files, and you should contact InstallShield support to learn about why and whether you need to upgrade.